# Equal meaning of conditional and passive conditional?

Tags: conditional-constructions, passive-voice

Take the following constructions:

> "How will you get home if someone steals your bike?"

or

> "How will you get home if your bike is stolen?"

Do they have any differences in the suggested ideas, beyond the emphasis?

Comment: I can discern no meaningful difference between the two versions.

Answer (score 2):

They mean the same thing, but the tenses are slightly different.

The first sentence implies the bike has not yet been stolen, because 'if someone steals' is (conditional) future tense.

The second sentence could refer to a bike that has *or* has not been stolen, because "if your bike is stolen" could be read as:

> "**if** [conditional] your bike **is stolen?** [future tense]"

or

> "**if** [a condition that has happened] your bike **is stolen?** [present tense]"